How to create an AppImage of a Python module that is developed in `pipenv`?
How do I create an AppImage of a Python module that is packaged by pipenv?
I came across Converting Python applications packaged with pip. But I have not figured out how apply it to pipenv.
I have the impression that for the above to work, I must first convert my Python module to a Python package in PyPI. Is this understanding correct? But I have not done that. My python module is developed in a virtual environment managed by pipenv.
